# how write a json sync with extra-fs

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when I write different values with extra-fs.
I'm doing a casino game test on 20 simultaneous balances, except that it doesn't seem to really work when I write it in my json.

So what happens is that as soon as I run my program, it executes 20 files, each with a different betting tactic, and as soon as I win or lose, it writes them to my json.
The only drawback is that as soon as I run it, it doesn't work properly.
it doesn't write well and also doesn't change all the values at the same time.

Here's my program, which writes 20 values simultaneously:

```
 async updateJson(mainValue, newValue) {
        if (!this.getJson) return ":(";

        try {
            const data = await fs.readFile(this.getJson, 'utf8');
            const balanceData = JSON.parse(data);
            balanceData[mainValue] = newValue;
      
            await fs.writeFile(this.getJson, JSON.stringify(balanceData, null, 2), 'utf8');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error:", err);
        }
}
```

here's the json before execution:

```
{
  "Balance1": 800,
  "Balance2": 800,
  "Balance3": 800,
  "Balance4": 800,
  "Balance5": 800,
  "Balance6": 800,
  "Balance7": 800,
  "Balance8": 800,
  "Balance9": 800,
  "Balance10": 800,
  "Balance11": 800,
  "Balance12": 800,
  "Balance13": 800,
  "Balance14": 800,
  "Balance15": 800,
  "Balance16": 800,
  "Balance17": 800,
  "Balance18": 800,
  "Balance19": 800,
  "Balance20": 800
}
```

after execution:

```
{
  "Balance1": 800,
  "Balance2": 800,
  "Balance3": 800,
  "Balance4": 800,
  "Balance5": 800,
  "Balance6": 800,
  "Balance7": 800,
  "Balance8": 800,
  "Balance9": 800.05,
  "Balance10": 800.1,
  "Balance11": 800,
  "Balance12": 800,
  "Balance13": 800,
  "Balance14": 800,
  "Balance15": 800,
  "Balance16": 800,
  "Balance17": 800,
  "Balance18": 800,
  "Balance19": 800,
  "Balance20": 800
}00
}
```

and my error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: ./Balance.json: Unexpected number in JSON at position 398
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.readFileSync (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:52:17)
    at Bet.retrieveData (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\bloCasino\bet\mainBet.js:12:36)
    at Americaine.bettingTactics (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\bloCasino\bet\crash\americaine.js:21:46)
    at Bet.betAlgo (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\bloCasino\bet\mainBet.js:61:33)
    at startBetting (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test.js:67:16)
    at startScript (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test.js:239:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test.js:37:17
Error: SyntaxError: ./Balance.json: Unexpected number in JSON at position 398
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.readFileSync (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:52:17)
    at Bet.retrieveData (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test\bet\mainBet.js:12:36)
    at contreAlembert.bettingTactics (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test\bet\crash\contreAlembert.js:15:46)       
    at Bet.betAlgo (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test\bet\mainBet.js:61:33)
    at startBetting (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test.js:77:16)
    at startScript (C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test.js:239:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\#\Desktop\SimulatorBetProject\test.js:37:17...
```

Comment: `as soon as I run my program, it executes 20 files` ... What do you mean by this? What files?

Comment: Do 20 processes write at the same time into the same file? That won't work. You have to coordinate the file access.

Comment: Yes, I write everything in the same file. How do I coordinate access to the file?

Comment: Do you have multiple processes or one process with async writes? If you have multiple processes, I would solve it at operating system level. If it's one process, I would solve it in the code.

Comment: I have a single process but several simultaneous actions with the json file

Comment: The posted answer should describe a solution. Each action has to wait for the previous action. I would prefer a similar approach with `writeFile` and `readFile` instead of `writeFileSync` and `readFileSync`. `writeFileSync` and `readFileSync` block the whole thread.

Comment: it's cool it makes more than one error problem it doesn't work on all the scales but only on one. Should we make a loop that does it one by one? Another problem is that the architecture of my program isn't designed that way. Is there a way?

Comment: thank you i found and i solved my problems !!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the way you write the changes to the file as you may be encountering multiple writes to the file, in the documentation for [`fs.fileWrite`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) it is mentioned that:

> It is unsafe to use fs.writeFile() multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback...

I would suggest keeping an in memory representation of your final JSON and manipulate that to be written upon change, instead of reading and writing for each change. In addition use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) and [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options).

Example of how that could work (untested):

```js
if (!this.getJson) return ":(";
const data = fs.readFileSync(this.getJson, 'utf8');
const balanceData = JSON.parse(data);

// Start the loops or whatever triggers the updateJson calls...

updateJson(mainValue, newValue) {
    try {
        balanceData[mainValue] = newValue;
      
        fs.writeFileSync(this.getJson, JSON.stringify(balanceData, null, 2), 'utf8');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error:", err);
    }
}
```